# SharePoint 2010 August CU

Tags: user-profile, service-pack-2

I just successfully installed the two-part (WSS and SharePoint Server) SP2 and confirmed build number is updated to `14.0.7015.1000`:

Does SP2 alone fix the following problem?

```
UserProfileServiceImportStatisticsWebPart:LoadControl failed, Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: ‘Boolean Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileImportJob.get_IsSynchronizationRunning()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this issue fixed in SP2. You dont need to apply the WSS sp2, simply Install the SP2 for server and if you have any language packs installed then SP2 for lps also required.

After that you have to run the config wizard on the all server in the farm.

Now make sure the server is uptodate, none of the database(content, services & config) says upgrade required.

Now start the USer profile sync services.

Comment: Thanks. I had more problems after that - had to get our admin to configure group policy for account that the Forefront services ran under, etc.